# Copiar tabla BBDD a array bidimensional PHP

Tags: php, pdo, array-bidimensional

Quiero copiar la tabla del servidor en SQL a un array bidimensional de PHP (array[][]). De tal forma que pueda acceder al array mediante: array[$i][$j] (siendo i las filas horziontales, y j las columnas verticales).

Para ello he utilizado este código:

```
$contMat = $bdd->prepare("SELECT * FROM materiales WHERE plan = :id AND usuario != :usuario");
$contMat->execute([':id'=>$id, ':usuario'=>$usuario]);

$resultado = $contMat->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($resultado as $value=>$valor) 
{
    
    if($value =="boli")
    {
        $matParticipantes[$vaule]=$valor;
    }
    
    if($value =="lapiz")
    {
        $matParticipantes[$vaule]=$valor;
    }
    
    if($value=="goma")
    {
        $matParticipantes[$vaule]=$valor;
    }
    
    if($value=="sacapuntas")
    {
        $matParticipantes[$vaule]=$valor;
    }
}
```

añado cómo es la tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi diea es que si yo quiero acceder a todos los materiales de ana
pueda hacer

```
$matParticipantes[1][1];
$matParticipantes[1][2];
$matParticipantes[1][3];
$matParticipantes[1][4];
```

Comment: Sospecho que estamos ante un mal diseño a nivel de base de datos. ¿Las columnas se llamarán siempre `boli, lapiz, goma y sacapuntas`? En ese caso, en vez de liarte con arrays de varias dimensiones, usa los nombres de cada columna para sacar los valores ... de hecho, aplicas una especie de solución inversa, preguntando por los nombres de columna en cada `if` de tu código, haciendo complicado un problema simple. Lo del mal diseño lo intuyo al ver que usas columnas para definir **tipos** ... Imaginemos que **solamente** `Ana` necesita dos materiales más, digamos, `cuaderno` y `mochila` ...

Comment: ... tendrás que crear dos nuevas columnas, **para algo que sólo `Ana` necesitará**. Y si `Juan` necesita una `pluma`, pues ooootra columna más ... y así sucesivamente. Tendrás columnas inútiles para algunos registros. Y todo eso se complicará cuando necesites contar, comparar, agrupar, etc... Quizá deberías crear una tabla `material` y otra tabla `usuario_material` donde expreses los materiales que usará cada usuario.

Comment: he encontrado una solcuión, la pongo por si a alguien le vale. Comaparto tu idea de que la BBDD está mal diseñada, pero dejare el código por si alguien puede reutilizarlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$selecMatPArt = $bdd->prepare("SELECT* FROM materiales WHERE plan = :id AND usuario != :usuario");
    $selecMatPArt->execute([':id'=>$id, ':usuario'=>$usuario]);

    $f=0;

    while ($row = $selecMatPArt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM))
    {
        for($c=0;$c<$nCol;$c++)
        {
            $matParticipantes[$f][$c]= $row[$c];
            
            //echo $row[$c];
        }

        $f++;

    }
```

El array matParticipantes es una copia de la tabla de MySQL para acceder por ejemplo con dos for anidados,